# How to find the set of non-merge changes in a TFS branch?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I know I can do a "compare" between two changesets and get a list of the changes made in the period of time between the changesets in question.

However, *from that list* I would like to *exclude* all changes that are the result of merge operations only (change types merge; merge, edit; merge, branch; etc.).

**My goal** is to get a list of what changes (edits, adds, deletes, ...) have been made *within the particular branch*, including to any files which have also had changes merged into the branch from other branches, without cluttering up the list with changes made in other branches and simply merged into my branch of interest.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a list of changes to a particular branch is quite easy.  In source control, just press `Ctrl-G`.  You can then filter on the branch and get a list of changes, and you can specify the change sets; then select Find.  This will include merges though.

Comment: *"This will include merges though."* Exactly. Getting the full set of changes is trivial; it's getting the full set of changes *except* for any merge-related changes that I can't find a way to do. (So while I don't believe I've used Ctrl+G specifically, I unfortunately don't really see this answer telling me anything I didn't already know.) I'm hoping there's a way to do that that doesn't involve writing a custom TFS client application, but with how often I find myself wanting to do it even that might be a time-saver...

Comment: If you always use a specific comment in your merge, and you have TFS Power Tools, you could use a command line wiql statement (power shell).  http://juliankay.com/development/querying-tfs-with-tfpt-exe-and-powershell/

Comment: Unfortunately, while *I* do use a specific pattern for merge checkin comments, others where I work often aren't quite as disciplined. I'm working on that and am making progress, but it's a slow process.

Comment: Okay, well it's not exactly sleek, but you could use excel to interrogate the data: http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

This may not completely solve your issue, but it will help I guess.

If you know about the source branches which would have merged to your branch then you can make use of the [TF MERGES COMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/656cs2x5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which will give you the changeset numbers on when the merges happened.